# css media queries applyed to a div

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a responsive table based on different `@media` breakpoints. Ex:

```
tbody tr {
  td {
    @media @lg {
      max-width: 70px;
    }
    @media @sm {
      max-width: 50px;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to reuse this table in a div of fixed width. The div width is `div.mycontainer{ width: 800px; }` therefore I would like the `@media @sm` rules to be applied to the table in the div regardless of the actual display width. Is it possible to trick the css to read the 'width for the media' from the div?

Thanks!

Comment: No. `media` can only be used for screens and so forth.

Comment: Is there a less css query dependent on the width of the container element. I would change media for something like `@container width>=768`

Comment: Nope, sorry. You would need something like JavaScript to handle this.